# How do I clear a deleted table view cell from a tableView in swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am deleting cell from a tableView like so:

[image]

Then, if I go to delete "milk" from the list, this is the result after the tableView data is reloaded.

[image]

When "milk" should have been deleted from the list. The item has been deleted in the data source, then the reload method is called on the tableView:

```
items.removeAtIndex(currentIndexPath!.row)
tableView.reloadData()
```

I don't know exactly why this is happening, or how to fix it, but my best guess is that the cell is put into a queue, then, when the tableView is reloaded, it is brought out and placed into the index path it was deleted from, so I suppose my question is, if this is true, how can I delete it from the tableView's queue?

Comment: Does your dataSource drive the numberOfRowsInSection method ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so from what I can see, one of two things is happening:

**1.** The array has deleted "Milk" correctly, but your cellForRowAtIndexPath method is using an old array, which hasn't been updated to reflect this change.

In this case, when "Milk" is removed, the numberOfRowsInSection method returns the number of items in your array (2).  But cellForRowAtIndexPath doesn't reflect this change, so still loads the data from the old list - "eggs", then "milk", then "Enter a new item" - but is only called twice, so only reached the "milk" stage.  Hence "Enter a new item" is removed.

**2.** (More likely)  Your currentIndexPath variable is wrong, and is actually the indexPath for the last item in this list, causing the wrong item to be removed from your array.  I'd maybe try just printing the value of currentIndexPath.row to check this.

Both of these of course assume that "Enter a new item" is part of your values list, as I cannot see any other possible way that cell could be being removed.  As a side note, if this is the case then I would definitely change that - your life will be 50x easier if you put permanent cells like that inside their own section.  Then you don't need to worry about them in cellForRowAtIndexPath

**Edit:**  Also, if I've mis-interpreted this, and my suggestions are not the case, then try printing your array at each stage, to check what's happening to it and when.  (i.e. in each Table View function, and just after you've attempted to remove that value.)